# Problem with installing Python in external drive

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, drive

I am a beginner in Python and PyCharm. I had installed both Python and PyCharm in my D drive, instead of C. But then, I was facing some issues, so had to uninstall and reinstall them in my C drive. Now, when I use the pip command in CMD, it says

`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe"  "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.`

I tried looking for solutions but have given up. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your path file is still leading to the pip in D: Go to path and change that to your C: directory for pip

Comment: Yes, I know this, but how do I do that? I tried changing the path directory in environment variables, but it's of no use.

Comment: Try @arnav's answer

Comment: Yup, I did, and it worked. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install via Python [website](https://www.python.org/downloads/) it could fix your terminal issues.

In PyCharm settings you can change your Python environnement (tutorial [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and I tried the following steps:

1. Open CMD as an administrator.
2. Write 'python -m pip install -U --force pip' in the CMD.
3. Restart your PC/laptop.
4. Try the pip command now.

Comment: OMG tysm, this worked! I hope PyCharm and Python also share the same modules now.